# Node application testing and LCOV report generation with Mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, lcov, codacy

My group recently started working on a previously existing Node application written entirely in ES6 (its been through a couple of different developers prior to us working on it). The application is minimally unit tested using Mocha and Nyan as the reporter for Mocha. The package.json file already contained the following command to run tests:

```
"test": "node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha  --compilers js:babel-core/register ./test/**/*.spec.js"
```

As part of our deployment cycle, we use a CI/CD pipeline with Travis and [Codacy](https://www.codacy.com/). As a result, in order to enable the "code coverage" portion of Codacy I needed to make some changes to the application repository and package.json file. The basic idea was to have Mocha generate an *.lcov* file which then is piped to Codacy in the Travis build script.

After doing some research i put together the following to generate the *lcov* file successfully:

```
    "build-test": "node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha -R mocha-lcov-reporter > coverage/coverage.lcov  --compilers js:babel-core/register ./test/**/*.spec.js --reporter nyan"
```

The problem is, I'm getting a Codacy parsing error for the *.lcov* file. I looked at lcov files for other projects and there seems to be extra data in the one I'm generating. For reference here is the generated lcov file:

```
0
0
0

[4A[5C-
[5C-
[5C-
[5C-
[4A[6C_,------,
[6C_|   /\_/\ 
[6C^|__( - .-) 
[6C  ""  "" 
[4ACONSTRUCTOR
 1
 0
 0

[4A[5C-_
[5C-_
[5C-_
[5C-_
[4A[7C_,------,
[7C_|  /\_/\ 
[7C~|_( ^ .^) 
[7C ""  "" 
[4ACONSTRUCTOR
 2
 0
 0

[4A[5C-_-
[5C-_-
[5C-_-
[5C-_-
[4A[8C_,------,
[8C_|   /\_/\ 
[8C^|__( ^ .^) 
[8C  ""  "" 
[4ACONSTRUCTOR
 3
 0
 0

[4A[5C-_-_
[5C-_-_
[5C-_-_
[5C-_-_
[4A[9C_,------,
[9C_|  /\_/\ 
[9C~|_( ^ .^) 
[9C ""  "" 
[4ACONSTRUCTOR
{"name":"from http://localhost:9200 searcher","hostname":"NCI-01966295-ML","pid":14596,"level":30,"msg":"Active","time":"2017-05-16T23:02:37.746Z","v":0}
{"name":"from http://localhost:9200 searcher","hostname":"NCI-01966295-ML","pid":14596,"level":30,"msg":"Temporarily Closed to Accrual","time":"2017-05-16T23:02:37.747Z","v":0}
 4
 0
 0

[4A[5C-_-_-
[5C-_-_-
[5C-_-_-
[5C-_-_-
[4A[10C_,------,
[10C_|   /\_/\ 
[10C^|__( ^ .^) 
[10C  ""  "" 
[4ACONSTRUCTOR
 5
 0
 0

[4A[5C-_-_-_
[5C-_-_-_
[5C-_-_-_
[5C-_-_-_
[4A[11C_,------,
[11C_|  /\_/\ 
[11C~|_( ^ .^) 
[11C ""  "" 
[4ACONSTRUCTOR
 6
 0
 0

[4A[5C-_-_-_-
[5C-_-_-_-
[5C-_-_-_-
[5C-_-_-_-
[4A[12C_,------,
[12C_|   /\_/\ 
[12C^|__( ^ .^) 
[12C  ""  "" 
[4ACONSTRUCTOR
 7
 0
 0

[4A[5C-_-_-_-_
[5C-_-_-_-_
[5C-_-_-_-_
[5C-_-_-_-_
[4A[13C_,------,
[13C_|  /\_/\ 
[13C~|_( ^ .^) 
[13C ""  "" 
[4ACONSTRUCTOR
 8
 0
 0

[4A[5C-_-_-_-_-
[5C-_-_-_-_-
[5C-_-_-_-_-
[5C-_-_-_-_-
[4A[14C_,------,
[14C_|   /\_/\ 
[14C^|__( ^ .^) 
[14C  ""  "" 
[4ACONSTRUCTOR
 9
 0
 0

[4A[5C-_-_-_-_-_
[5C-_-_-_-_-_
[5C-_-_-_-_-_
[5C-_-_-_-_-_
[4A[15C_,------,
[15C_|  /\_/\ 
[15C~|_( ^ .^) 
[15C ""  "" 
[4A




  9 passing (20ms)
```

I observed a few things regarding the npm scripts (test and build-test):

- test works correctly, informing me that 9 tests are passing
- If I run build-test without "--reporter nyan" it says "no coverage data found, make sure your code is properly instrumented"
- Everything in the build-test line of code seems to be necessary.

I'm at my wits end to be honest. I have no idea why the *.lcov* file is having parsing issues. All I really need is to use mocha with mocha-lcov-reporter to generate a valid *.lcov* file. It doesn't seem like it should be all that difficult.

Thank you for any help provided. I appreciate it.

Comment: You are trying to run the coverage report with 2 reporters. You have `-R mocha-lcov-reporter` as well as `--reporter nyan`. As per `mocha --help` in cli `-R` is short for `--reporter`. This wont solve the error you are getting but may help narrow it down.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `nyc`?

Untested example of the command-line above using `nyc`

```
"build-test": "./node_modules/.bin/nyc --reporter lcov --reporter nyan mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register ./test/**/*.spec.js
```